# Javascript - find in object based on key and extract the found data

Tags: javascript

I have a **localstorage** object, and I need to find all data and extract it based on the key.

Example of object:

```
    Storage {
    agency-list|radio-radio2: "true", 
    agency|radio-radio1: "true", length: 2
.....}
```

This is how I get the param for searching:

```
let formID = $('form').attr('id');
let regex  = new RegExp("^" + formID + "|");
```

For example, I would like to extract all **key value**, where the key is beginning with **agency|**, in separate array or object.

What is the best approach for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination `Object.keys()` and `filter` can help you :

```
let formID = $('form').attr('id');
let regex  = new RegExp(`^${formID}|`);
const Storage = {
      "agency-list|radio-radio2": "true", 
      "agency|radio-radio1": "true",
      length: 2 
};
const agencies = Object.keys(Storage).filter( key => regex.test(key));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Object.keys() method to iterate over your keys

```
let Storage = {
"agency-list|radio-radio2": "true", 
"agency|radio-radio1": "true",
length: 2 }
let otherStorage = [];
Object.keys(Storage).forEach(key=>{
    if(key.startsWith("agency|")){
        otherStorage.push(key);
    } 
});
console.log(otherStorage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop through all your object's properties, test if the prop matches the regex, and add it to result if it does.

```
let result = {};
for(let prop in storage){
    if(prop.match(regex)){
         result[prop] = storage[prop];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn your storage into an array with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
2. Filter the entries with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and check the regex with `test`.
3. Put everything back together into an object with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

I also used destructuring parameters `[key, value]`, since `Object.entries` outputs everything as an array of `[key, value]` arrays.

```js
let formID = $('form').attr('id');
let regex  = new RegExp("^" + formID + "|");

Object.entries(localStorage)
  .filter(([key, value]) => regex.test(key))
  .reduce((obj, [key, value]) => (obj[key] = value, obj), {});
```